# wolkenkit: How to localization

Tags: localization, internationalization, intl, wolkenkit

The data I store is at the moment written in english. So I plan to make this content localized/translatable and would like to give this option to users.

Here are my user stories:

(1) As a user I want to select the preferred language of my content (e.g. german). If the text is not available in german, please give me the content in the fallback language (e.g. english).

(2) As a user I want to be able to translate a given model.

Given the following:

1) A model, e.g. `Message` with two properties: `title` and `description`. It can be expected these two properties are in english (by default).

2) A command, e.g. `translateMessage` which will receive a payload with: `title`, `description` and `locale`.

What's an accepted way to handle localization of those models?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that your question is pretty broad, and maybe is more about the correct design of your domain than about wolkenkit itself. Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you have tried so far, what you want to achieve, …?

Comment: Updated. I hope, this makes it more clear.

Comment: Yes, it does! Is the list of languages known in advance?

Comment: It should be possible to add them on the fly. So I would say, the list of languages is also a model.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I come up with:

Let's say our `Message` will have the following properties (in Typescript):

```
{
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

I would extend it with a translations object. Where each key in there is a locale and has an object with translated strings.

```
{
  title: string;
  description: string;
  translations: {
    [key: string]: {
      title: string;
      description: string;
    }
  }
}
```

The `readModel` will be the same as above and it is up to the client to decide which strings to display.

The command `translateMessage` will receive the payload as described above and publish an event with that. The `readModel` will react to that event in a way, that it pushes the new payload data onto the `translations` object in that model.

For model creation, if the data is received in a different locale than the default one, then the event handler will put those translated strings prefix with the locale they were written in, into the root, e.g. `model.title` can be something like `[de] Nachrichtentitel`. The model would look like this:

```
{
  title: '[de] Nachrichtentitel'
  description: '[de] Nachrichteninhalt'
  translations: {
    de: {
      title: 'Nachrichtentitel'
      description: 'Nachrichteninhalt'
    }
  }
}
```

You see any problems with that? Are there other already established best-practices on how to do that?